# How to use assemblyId when specifying a dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

One of the builds from the project that I am working on, creates as artifact composed of multiple "parts" that can be distinguished by the so called assemblyId (basically we use different assembly files to create these different parts..)

Lets assume that that build outputs 2 different parts of the same artifact, the difference in naming is the "standalone" part:

```
artifactName-2.20.0.zip
artifactName-2.20.0-standalone.zip
```

Next, i need to do some unpacking, and I need to work with **artifactName-2.20.0-standalone.zip** and I am not sure how to do that, if it is even possible to do that...

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactName</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <includes>**/*.exe</includes>
    <outputDirectory>xxx</outputDirectory>            
</artifactItem>
```

The specification from above, will take into consideration the first part **artifactName-2.20.0.zip** while I would be interested in taking the **standalone** one...

How can I do this ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are talking about is the `classifier` which can be set as

`<classifier>standalone</classifier>`.